Android: Run Time Permissions not working - App Settings Showing No Requested Permissions even when asked for (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
I'm working a background remover app from an image and upon the background removal process, I am supposed to download it to the download's folder butI keep getting the exception that no such file name found. So i tried asking for runtime permissions before downloading and i am facing an issue where my Android app is not showing the requested permissions in the app settings. I've declared the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in my AndroidManifest.xml and am requesting it at runtime using ActivityCompat.requestPermissions.
Despite this, the app settings page doesn't list the permission as requested. I've tried the following:
My build.gradle (app) file has minSdk set to 24 and targetSdk set to 34 and in my AndroidManifest file i have set targetApi to 31 and I am testing it on my OnePlus 12R device.
In order to ask for runtime permissions I am using the following code :
private fun requestRuntimePermissions() {
        when {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this@ImageStaging,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                // You can use the API that requires the permission.
                Log.d("PermGrant", "Permission already granted...")
            }
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                this@ImageStaging, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) -> {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ImageStaging)
                builder.setMessage("Permission to write is required to download the image to your storage...")
                builder.setTitle("Permission Required").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@ImageStaging, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), writepermcode)
                    dialog.dismiss()
                })
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                })
                builder.show()

            }
            else -> {
                // You can directly ask for the permission.
                // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@ImageStaging, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), writepermcode)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when (requestCode) {
            writepermcode -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
                            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow
                    // in your app.
                    Toast.makeText(this@ImageStaging, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because
                    // the feature requires a permission that the user has denied.
                    // At the same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to
                    // system settings in an effort to convince the user to change
                    // their decision.
                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@ImageStaging)
                    builder.setMessage("Permission to write is required to download the image to your storage...")
                    builder.setTitle("Permission Required").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                        val intent: Intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS)
                        val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                        intent.setData(uri)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    })
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                        dialog.dismiss()
                    })
                    builder.show()
                }
                return
            }

            // Add other 'when' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
            else -> {
                // Ignore all other requests.
                requestRuntimePermissions()
            }
        }
    }

Upon running the app on my device i am expecting to see the app having requested at least a single external storage request, but i am getting the following output :
enter image description here

Handle permissions for android 13 and above.
private fun checkStoragePermission(): Boolean {
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        val audioPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
        )
    
         val videoPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
             this,
             Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO
         )
    
         val imagePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
             this,
             Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES
         )
         return audioPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && videoPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && imagePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    } else {
        val storagePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        val courseLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )
        return storagePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && courseLocationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
}

And add these lines in manfest.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>



This seems to do the trick for asking Run-Time Permissions. But I am still not able  to download my generated png image to my downloads file. That's another issue though. Thanks!

Add Permission in AndroidManifest.xml File
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


I have already added it, but still the app says no request has been asked for by the app

can you provide the manifest code? also, try to uninstall the app and run it again.
